# laravel maatwebsite-excel package: setting the column width does not work

Tags: maatwebsite-excel

I use version 3 of laravel maatwebsite-excel.
I try to set the width of a column, to do that I use the PhpSpreadsheet native method in a AfterSheet event like this:

```
public function registerEvents(): array
{
    return [

        AfterSheet::class    => function(AfterSheet $event) {

            $event->sheet->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(32);
        }
    ]
 }
```

When i use:
$event->sheet->getColumnDimension('D')->setVisible(false);
it works, but setting the width doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 4):

Need to set column autosize to false

```
$event->sheet->getColumnDimension('D')->setAutoSize(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are exporting form view you can directly use

```
style="word-wrap:break-word"
```

Just make sure your Export class is not implementing **ShouldAutoSize**